Guardar datos de un formulario, en campos adentro del perfil de un usuario en Woocommerce
Estoy tratando de guardar algunos datos de un formulario, en unos campos personalizados en Woocommerce, puedo crear la nueva pestaña que quiero adentro del perfil y los label correspondientes donde se supone debería alojarse la información, pero cada vez que relleno el formulario, los datos no quedan alojados.
Mi codigo es el siguiente:
PHP para obtener los datos:
// Hook para ejecutar cuando se envíe el formulario
function guardar_datos_wpforms($entry, $form_data) {
    $form_id = 123; // Cambia esto al ID de tu formulario WPForms
    
    if ($form_data['id'] == $form_id) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if ($user_id) {
            // Obtener datos del formulario
            $fields = $entry['fields']; // Campos del formulario
            
            // Cambia '1' y '2' por los IDs reales de los campos en tu formulario
            $nombre_mascota = isset($fields['1']) ? sanitize_text_field($fields['1']['value']) : '';
            
            // Registrar datos para depuración
            error_log('Formulario ID: ' . $form_id);
            error_log('Usuario ID: ' . $user_id);
            error_log('Nombre de la Mascota: ' . $nombre_mascota);
            error_log('Edad de la Mascota: ' . $edad_mascota);
            
            // Guardar en el perfil del usuario
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'nombre_mascota', $nombre_mascota);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'edad_mascota', $edad_mascota);
        }
    }
}
add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'guardar_datos_wpforms', 10, 2);



PHP para guardar los datos:
// Guardar la información de la pestaña 'Mascota'
function guardar_pestaña_mascota($user_id) {
    // Verificar que el usuario tiene permisos para editar su propio perfil
    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Verificar que los datos están presentes en $_POST
    if (isset($_POST['nombre_mascota'])) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'nombre_mascota', sanitize_text_field($_POST['nombre_mascota']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['edad_mascota'])) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'edad_mascota', sanitize_text_field($_POST['edad_mascota']));
    }
}
add_action('personal_options_update', 'guardar_pestaña_mascota');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'guardar_pestaña_mascota');



PHP para crear la pestaña y guardar ahi la info
// Añadir la pestaña 'Mascota' al perfil del usuario
function agregar_pestaña_mascota($user) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php _e('Información de la Mascota', 'twentytwentyfour'); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="nombre_mascota"><?php _e('Nombre del Perro'); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="nombre_mascota" id="nombre_mascota" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('nombre_mascota', $user->ID)); ?>" class="regular-text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'agregar_pestaña_mascota');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'agregar_pestaña_mascota');


Estoy usando wordpress + wpforms

No tengo reputación y no puedo hacer un comentario con el que seguramente entenderías lo que pienso.
Debes asegurarse de que los IDs de los campos ('1' y '2') coincidan con los IDs de los campos que estás utilizando en WPForms. Si los IDs son diferentes, los datos no se recogerán correctamente.
No estoy usando WPForm, pero no estas obteniendo el campo para la edad de la mascota, 'edad_mascota'
Un ejemplo:
$edad_mascota = isset($fields['2']) ? sanitize_text_field($fields['2']['value']) : '';
También debes asegurarte de que te coincidan los IDs con los IDs de tu formulario de WPForms.
Quizá este sea el error, Asegúrate de que coincidan con los nombres de los campos en tu formulario las claves de $_POST['nombre_mascota'] y $_POST['edad_mascota'] 
Sin hacer la prueba definitiva, puedes ver si esto es lo que solucione tu problema
// Hook para ejecutar cuando se envíe el formulario
function guardar_datos_wpforms($entry, $form_data) {
    $form_id = 123; // Cambia esto al ID de tu formulario WPForms
    
    if ($form_data['id'] == $form_id) {
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if ($user_id) {
            // Obtener datos del formulario
            $fields = $entry['fields']; // Campos del formulario
            
            // Cambia '1' y '2' por los IDs reales de los campos en tu formulario
            $nombre_mascota = isset($fields['1']) ? sanitize_text_field($fields['1']['value']) : '';
            $edad_mascota = isset($fields['2']) ? sanitize_text_field($fields['2']['value']) : ''; // Línea añadida
            
            // Registrar datos para depuración
            error_log('Formulario ID: ' . $form_id);
            error_log('Usuario ID: ' . $user_id);
            error_log('Nombre de la Mascota: ' . $nombre_mascota);
            error_log('Edad de la Mascota: ' . $edad_mascota);
            
            // Guardar en el perfil del usuario
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'nombre_mascota', $nombre_mascota);
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'edad_mascota', $edad_mascota);
        }
    }
}
add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'guardar_datos_wpforms', 10, 2);

Espero sea la solución, aún asi, tratare de hacer alguna pruba en entorno real
